# Custom icons for kml layer using in Google maps Api

Tags: parsing, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

I want to display data from kml file, which is situated here http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?f=q&msa=0&output=kml&msid=201434694813577429889.0004ba2d12b7538131e5e .

It is output from MyPlaces. I want to do more stuff with it - change icons, use clustering and so on, so embedding is not good solution.

I've tried to load the file using `KmlLayer` in `GoogleMapsApi`, which works, but I don't know, how to change icons and how to get data for each marker (coordinates, description, ..).

Actually, what I need is just the access to the data in kml, I am able to do all other programming on my own. The file is continuously changing so I need to do all the stuff online.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3rd party KML parser (through a proxy) like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/).  They render the KML using native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, you can modify those using the Google Maps Javascript API.  When you do that you lose the benefit of KmlLayer's tile based rendering, so with complex KML, you may have performance issues.

[example with your KML (seems to have a character encoding issue)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid%3D201434694813577429889.0004ba2d12b7538131e5e%26output%3Dkml%26msa%3D0)

Comment: Yes, I have seen this parser. It works fine, if the kml is on the same domain as my pages. But when I tried to parse kml from MyPlaces it reports errors (because of security reasons - the browser is blocking it). Why does your example work?

Comment: It is loading the KML through a [proxy](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml/wiki/Proxy)